# Apache2 & PHP showing blank page

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I've tried to install PHP and Apache2, however when I access the file, it just shows a blank page.

I've installed the packages php, apache2, php-mysql (and some others)

I've already tried pretty much everything that I could find on the Internet.

I'm sorry if I'm not providing enough info, I will give any info that I can.

Comment: Thanks but none of that works for me, I'm sorry

Comment: And how did you install them?

Comment: with the packages I've mentioned. Honestly, I've just followed some text I found on the internet. I first installed mysql, then the php package and apache2 and some others like php-mysql. Yep, I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: You have to list the commands and gives us the link else we will all be guessing!

Comment: well I don't know them. I guess I need a list myself, on how to clean remove all of it and start over again. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Run `systemctl status apache2` and `php -version` and let me see the output

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

1. Install php for Apache with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`
2. Restart apache with

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
3. Place code to the `/var/www/html/phpinfo.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
4. Navigate web-browser to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`.

These steps will help to check that PHP is working normally.

---

Note: this method works for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS, 21.04 and 21.10 too.

Comment: He needs to reset `apache` service for modules to get loaded i believe.

Answer (score 0):

A black page could be because of a php fatal error (or could be an php non-fatal error if no content was still send to the browser) when `display_errors` is set to `off` in the `php.ini`.

[Look at the php log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) to get back the error log.

It could be also because the php file content is send as raw text to your navigator, look at the "html source code" from your browser to make sure you don't see php code. If you do the php module isn't setup properly with apache.